# Prove / Disprove : if $a \neq 0$ and is not invertible so $a$ is a zero divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

R is a commutative ring with an identity element. 
Prove or disprove that if

$a \in R ,\; a \neq 0 \;$and is not invertible  so  $a$ is a zero divisor.

I tried to pick $\;x \in R,\; x\neq 0\;$ s.t $\;ax = 0$

My first try led me to pick $\;x = ax-x$

$ax = a(ax-x) = a^2x - ax\;$ Then I thought that if i could prove that $\;a\;$ is idempotence I could prove that $\;ax = 0$

Comment: my bad , will edit now

Comment: Awesome, thanks for taking the time to fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$ an element distinct of $-1$ and $1$ and $0$ is not invertible and is not a zero divisor

Comment: if I understand correctly you pick $a = 0$ which is against one of the demands

Comment: @EliranTurgeman Take $a=2$, if you prefer. But the answer states to take *any* element not among $1$, $-1$ and $0$.